# classList.toggle() behaves strange

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, queryselector

I am trying to learn Javascript by creating this very simple todo app. I can type some value in input. When pressed enter or submit button, the value from input tag is added to the ul as a list. Then a class 'list-item' is added to that li tag.

My issue is: I want to cross any individual list when clicked. I have used following code for that. I have the 'cross' style in my CSS, but the problem is that my code does not cross every individual list. It crosses every-other one. I tried forEach as well and the result is same.

```js
const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('list-item');

for (let i=0; i<listItems.length; i++) {
    
    listItems[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log(listItems[i])
        listItems[i].classList.toggle('cross');
    })
}
```

my whole javascript :

```js
const input = document.getElementById('main-input')
const submit = document.getElementById('submit')
const ul = document.getElementById('to_dos');
const del = document.getElementById('del')

//clicking submit button
submit.addEventListener('click', function() {
    addList()
})

//pressing enter key
input.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault()
        addList()
        
    }
})

//add new todo in the list from input
const addList = () => {
    const newToDo = document.createElement('LI')
    newToDo.classList.add('list-item')
    newToDo.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value))
        
        
    ul.appendChild(newToDo)
    input.value = "" 
    
    //cross the completed tasks
    const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('li.list-item');
    
    for (let i=0; i<listItems.length; i++) {
        
        listItems[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            console.log(listItems[i])
            listItems[i].classList.toggle('cross');
        })
    }


    //delete button
    del.addEventListener('click', function() {
        const completedItems = document.querySelectorAll('.cross');
        completedItems.forEach(
            completedItem => {
                completedItem.classList.add('hide')
            }
        )
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your codepen, you are assigning the click listener incorrectly. Rather than attaching a listener to each added item individually, you are loop through ALL the items EACH time a new one is added - and when you compound event listeners like that it can have undesireable results.

In your `addList` function, rather than looping through all inputs with this:

```
        //cross the completed tasks
        const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('li');
        
        listItems.forEach(listItem => listItem.addEventListener('click', e => {
            e.target.classList.toggle('cross');
        }))
```

Just attach the listener to the new one added:

```
        newToDo.addEventListener('click', e => {
            e.target.classList.toggle('cross');
        })
```

Example: https://codepen.io/chayashital/pen/jOGaWgJ#_=_

Comment: I edited my code as you suggested. Unfortunately, It did not make a change, yet

Comment: what is so strange to me is that it works for alternate list . as you can see it my codepen:
https://codepen.io/chayashital/pen/jOGaWgJ

Comment: I looked at the codepen and changed my answer. Check it out and see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

you just forget to add dot (.) at the beggining of the **querySelectorAll** method.
in your case you told **querySelectorAll** method to find all *list-item* tag so that dot will change the meaning to find all *list-item* class.
and **querySelectorAll** will return **HTMLCollection** not **Array** so the **forEach** method will not work you should return it to a **Array** using **Array()** function or the following way.

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('.list-item')]
.forEach(function(element){
    element.addEventListener("click", function(){
        element.classList.toggle("cross")
})
})
```

Comment: thanks you. I edited the code as per your suggestion but it still behaves same.